# How can I persist dialogData across different nodes?

Tags: node.js, botframework

As it says in the documentation for the Microsoft Bot Framework, they have different types of data. One of them is the dialogData, privateConversationData, conversationData and userData.

By default, it seems the userData is/should be prepared to handle the persistency across nodes, however the dialogData should be used for temporary data.

As it says here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-waterfall

> If the bot is distributed across multiple compute nodes, each step of
>   the waterfall could be processed by a different node, therefore it's
>   important to store bot data in the appropriate data bag

So, basically, if I have two nodes, how/why should I used dialogData at all, as I cannot guarantee it will be kept across nodes? It seems that if you have more than one node, you should just use userData.

Comment: you are correct, use one of these 3 databags `privateConversationData`, `conversationData` and `userData`

Comment: So, the conversationData is synced between nodes too? I read that only the userData was handled that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've asked the docs team to remove the last portion of the sentence: "therefore it's important to store bot data in the appropriate data bag".  It is misleading.  The Bot Builder is restful and stateless.  Each of the dialogData, privateConversationData, conversationData and userData are stored in the State Service: so any "compute node" will be able to retrieve the data from any of these objects.

Please note: the default Connector State Service is intended only for prototyping, and should not be used with production bots.  Please use the [Azure Extensions](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/) or implement a custom state client.

This blog post might also be helpful: [Saving State data with BotBuilder-Azure in Node.js](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/07/21/saving-state-azure-nodejs/)

Comment: Thanks! That actually makes more sense. I couldn't grasp how the complete architecture would work. Reading that page and the Manage State Data after your explanation makes more sense. Specially after this: "Each of the dialogData, privateConversationData, conversationData and userData are stored in the State Service: so any "compute node" will be able to retrieve the data from any of these objects"

Comment: Also, this also confussed me: "By default, data that is stored using the userData, privateConversationData, and conversationData properties is set to persist after the conversation ends", like the dialogData was never persisted. That is in the Manage State Data page.